# Can I directly serialize to a file using PHP's thrift library?

Tags: php, file, serialization, thrift

> Related: [Apache Thrift: Serializing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29420252/260610)

Hi guys : I am noting that the PHP thrift extensions don't appear to have a TFileTransport class.  This leads me to wonder : what is  the mechanism for writing a thrift object to a FILE in PHP ?

Unfortunately, available documentation is focused on the client/server model for using thrift : but I need to use PHP to serialize binary thrift files on disc, which contain a stream of thrift objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending TPhpStream by overriding:

```
private static function inStreamName() {
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
      return 'php://stdin';
    }
    return 'php://input';   }
```

and you would also probably need to alter open method to open write file of your choosing. In case you need it, here is [nice tutorial about php streams.](http://www.sk89q.com/2010/04/introduction-to-php-streams/)

If that does not work out for you, consider using TMemoryBuffer to serialize to string, and than you will find your way to put that into a file.

Comment: as far as I am reading it in, it checks if php is started as command line (cli = command line interface), if so then use standard unix input. Otherwise use input stream provided by http server.