# Apache Thrift: Serializing data

Tags: java, php, thrift

> RELATED QUESTION:
>   [Can I directly serialize to a file using PHP's thrift library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499076/can-i-directly-serialize-to-a-file-using-phps-thrift-library)

I have to use apache thrift to integrate two systems. But instead of the usual, which have a client / server files that communicates with each other (like the thrift examples). The application must generate a zip file with the thrift entries serialized in order to be imported on the other application manually. So there's no direct communication at all.

I need to to this in PHP and all I have is a Java example which have the following code:

```
package br.gov.saude.esus.transport.test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.thrift.TBase;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.TFieldIdEnum;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport;

import br.gov.saude.esus.thrift.thrift.CidadaoTransportThrift;
import br.gov.saude.esus.thrift.thrift.EnderecoTransportThrift;
import br.gov.saude.esus.thrift.thrift.SexoThrift;
import br.gov.saude.esus.thrift.thrift.TipoSanguineoThrift;

public class ExemploThriftCidadaoJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CidadaoTransportThrift> cidadaos = new ArrayList<CidadaoTransportThrift>();
        cidadaos.add(createCidadaoExemplo1());
        cidadaos.add(createCidadaoExemplo2());

        final File f = new File("c:\\temp\\cidadaos_exemplo.zip");
        ZipOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            for (CidadaoTransportThrift cidadaoTransportThrift : cidadaos) {
                byte[] data;
                try {
                    String entryName = "";
                    if (isNotBlank(cidadaoTransportThrift.getCns())) {
                        entryName = "-" + cidadaoTransportThrift.getNumeroProntuarioCnes() + "-" + cidadaoTransportThrift.getNumeroProntuario();
                    }
                    entryName = cidadaoTransportThrift.getCns() + "-" + entryName + ".cidadao";
                    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryName));
                    data = serialize(cidadaoTransportThrift);
                    out.write(data);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                out.closeEntry();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static CidadaoTransportThrift createCidadaoExemplo1() {
        CidadaoTransportThrift cidadao = new CidadaoTransportThrift();
        cidadao.setCns("09876543210987");
        cidadao.setCpf("01234567890");
        cidadao.setDataNascimento(new Date().getTime());

        // Nome da mãe
        // caso o cidadão não possua o nome da mãe deve preencher o campo "desconhece o nome da mãe" com verdadeiro
        // caso preencher o campo "desconhece o nome da mãe" com verdadeiro o campo nome da mãe passa a ser obrigatório
        cidadao.setDesconheceNomeMae(false);
        cidadao.setNomeMae("NOME DA MAE");

        cidadao.setEmail("email@docidadao.com.br");
        // Escolaridade
        // usar tabelas de referência (Escolaridade) coluna "Código"
        // caso não existir utilizar o código "15" ou não preencher
        cidadao.setEscolaridadeId(2L);

        EnderecoTransportThrift endereco = new EnderecoTransportThrift();
        endereco.setArea("1");
        // Bairro
        // o e-SUS busca a referência do bairro pelo campo:
        // Dne -> código do bairro registrado na base de dados do correio
        // caso o código Dne do bairro seja encontrado na base do e-SUS os dados da localidade e UF são encontrados com base no Dne do bairro
        endereco.setBairroDne("000654");
        // caso não exista código Dne o e-SUS fará a busca pelo nome do bairro e pela localidade
        // caso a busca pelo nome e localidade não retorne um registro, o bairro informado será cadastrado no e-SUS
        endereco.setBairroNome("bairro nome");
        endereco.setComplemento("complemento");
        // Localidade
        // o e-SUS busca a referência da localidade/município pela ordem dos campo abaixo
        // Dne -> código da localidade registrada na base de dados do correio
        // Ibge
        // se mesmo com os três códigos o município não for encontrado o e-SUS não importará o campo
        endereco.setLocalidadeDne("00008452");
        endereco.setLocalidadeIbge("420540");
        endereco.setMicroArea("1");

        // Sem número
        // caso o enderço não possua um número deve ser preenchido o campo Sem Número com true. Se o valor for falso o campo número passa a ser obrigatório
        endereco.setSemNumero(false);
        endereco.setNumero("123");
        endereco.setPontoReferencia("ponto de referência do endereço");
        endereco.setUfSigla("SC");
        cidadao.setEndereco(endereco);

        // Estado Civil
        // usar tabelas de referência (Estao Civil) coluna "Código"
        // caso não existir não preencher
        cidadao.setEstadoCivilId(1L);

        cidadao.setEstrangeiro(false);

        // Etnia
        // usar tabelas de referência (Etnia) coluna "Código"
        // caso não existir não preencher
        cidadao.setEtniaId(65L);

        cidadao.setFaleceu(false);

        // Municípiio
        // o e-SUS busca a referência da localidade/município pela ordem dos campo abaixo
        // Dne -> código da localidade registrada na base de dados do correio
        // Ibge
        // Cep
        // se mesmo com os três códigos o município não for encontrado o e-SUS não importará o campo
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoDne("00008452");
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoIbge("420540");
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoCep("88036003");

        // Não possui cns
        // Este campo tem a função de indicar, manualmente, que o cidadão não possui um CNS, caso marcado com falso o campo CNS se torna obrigatório
        cidadao.setNaoPossuiCns(false);

        cidadao.setNisPisPasep("1234567");
        cidadao.setNomeCompleto("ALEXANDRE MATTJE");

        // número do prontuario e numero prontuário cnes
        // Indica o número do prontuário do cidadão em uma determinada unidade de saúde
        // Para registrar um cidadão com número de prontuário em cada unidade de saúde deve se exportar uma linha com todos os dados do cidadão para cada unidade de saúde
        cidadao.setNumeroProntuario("123456");
        cidadao.setNumeroProntuarioCnes("1234567");

        // Raça Cor
        // Campo obrigatório
        // usar tabelas de referência (Etnia) coluna "Código"
        // caso não existir não preencher
        // Caso for 5-indígena o campo Etnia deve ser preenchido
        cidadao.setRacaCorId(4L);

        cidadao.setSexo(SexoThrift.MASCULINO);
        cidadao.setTelefoneCelular("4898765432");
        cidadao.setTelefoneContato("4890876543");
        cidadao.setTelefoneResidencial("4876543219");
        cidadao.setTipoSanguineo(TipoSanguineoThrift.A_NEGATIVO);
        return cidadao;
    }

    private static CidadaoTransportThrift createCidadaoExemplo2() {
        // Exemplo de cidadão com o mínimo necessário
        CidadaoTransportThrift cidadao = new CidadaoTransportThrift();
        cidadao.setDataNascimento(new Date().getTime());

        cidadao.setDesconheceNomeMae(true);

        // caso for estrangeiro for falso o campo município de nascimento passa a ser obrigatório
        // caso for verdadeiro o campo município pode ser vazio
        cidadao.setEstrangeiro(false);
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoDne("00008452");
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoIbge("420540");
        cidadao.setMunicipioNascimentoCep("88036003");

        cidadao.setNaoPossuiCns(false);
        cidadao.setCns("09876543210987");

        cidadao.setNomeCompleto("ALEXANDRE MATTJE");

        // Raça Cor
        // Campo obrigatório
        // usar tabelas de referência (Etnia) coluna "Código"
        // caso não existir não preencher
        // Caso for 5-indígena o campo Etnia deve ser preenchido
        cidadao.setRacaCorId(4L);

        cidadao.setSexo(SexoThrift.MASCULINO);

        return cidadao;
    }

    public static byte[] serialize(TBase<?, ? extends TFieldIdEnum> thrift) throws TException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TIOStreamTransport transport = new TIOStreamTransport(baos);
        TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        thrift.write(protocol);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void unserialize(byte[] data, TBase<?, ? extends TFieldIdEnum> thrift) throws TException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        TIOStreamTransport transport = new TIOStreamTransport(bais);
        TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        thrift.read(protocol);
    }

    public static Long castToLong(Object value, Long defaultValue) {
        if (value != null) {
            if (value instanceof Long) {
                return (Long) value;
            } else if (value instanceof Number) {
                return new Long(((Number) value).longValue());
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                try {
                    return value.equals("") ? defaultValue : new Long((String) value);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exn) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            } else if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
                return ((BigInteger) value).longValue();
            } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
                return ((BigDecimal) value).longValue();
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static Long castToLong(Object value) {
        return castToLong(value, null);
    }

    public static boolean isBlank(String text) {
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0, iSize = text.length(); i < iSize; i++) {
                if (text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isNotBlank(String nome) {
        return !isBlank(nome);
    }

    public static Integer castToInteger(Object value, Integer defaultValue) {
        if (value != null) {
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                return (Integer) value;
            } else if (value instanceof Number) {
                return new Integer(((Number) value).intValue());
            } else if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
                return ((BigInteger) value).intValue();
            } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
                return ((BigDecimal) value).intValue();
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                try {
                    return value.equals("") ? defaultValue : new Integer((String) value);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exn) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static Integer castToInteger(Object value) {
        return castToInteger(value, null);
    }

}
```

So far everything I know is that I would use those two lines to start serializing the data:

```
$stdout = new TPhpStream(TPhpStream::MODE_W);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($stdout);
```

But I don't know how to get the serialized data in order to create the zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Thrift\Transport\TMemoryBuffer;
use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;

function serialize($thrift) {
  $transport = new TMemoryBuffer();
  $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
  $thrift->write($protocol);
  $protocol->getTransport()->flush();

  return $transport->getBuffer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did like this.

```
    $transporte = new tools\TransporteClass(
        $uuidDadoSerializado,
        tools\TipoDadosSerializado::ATIVIDADE_COLETIVA, // 6
        $cnes,
        3519071, // Hortolandia
        TBinarySerializer::serialize($atividadeColetivaMaster)
    );

    $sTransporte = TBinarySerializer::serialize($transporte);
```

Comment: Hortolandia hahahahaha

Comment: @FranciscoAlbert esqueci de tirar